# Checkbox in tableview checked based on selection

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I've implemented a custom tablemodel based on `QAbstractItemModel`. The first column in the ttble includes a checkbox. Selection of a row is enabled. 
I'm trying to implement following behaviour:
If I click on the row I want that the checkbox in the first column to be checked or unchecked. How can I do that? It only works if I click on the checkbbox since a `setData()` with `QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole` is triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to do that is listen to the [pressed](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#pressed) signal of [QAbstractItemView](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html). The QModelIndex you receive has the row where a mouse butten was pressed, with that you can set the checkbox to checked yourself.